# Determine the current binlog file with python-mysql-replication

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using the [python-mysql-replication](https://github.com/julien-duponchelle/python-mysql-replication) package to consume the MySQL binlog. The current binlog position is accessible as shown below, but I'm unable to access the current binlog file, which I'd need if I want to restart the process and resume from the last position.

```py
stream = BinLogStreamReader(
    connection_settings=mysql_connection,
    server_id=server_id,
    blocking=True,
    resume_stream=True,
    only_events=[DeleteRowsEvent, WriteRowsEvent, UpdateRowsEvent],
)

print('Current position:', binlogevent.packet.log_pos)
```

Is the binlog file name for a particular event made available through this API? If not, are there any recommendations for resuming from the last-read position in the log?

Answer (score 0):

The current log file is accessible via `stream.log_file`